Select Count em duas tabelas
Estou montando uma rotina para mesclar contas que possuem fornecedores diferentes.
As tabelas são DUPLICATAS e VENCIDAS
Basicamente quero contar quantas contas tem em cada uma das tabelas acima cujo cod_fornecedor seja 318, por exemplo.
Após isso, apresentar na tela o resuldado encontrado e aplicar um update para atualizar o cod_fornecedor de 318 para 50, por exemplo.
Montei esse select no IBExpert, mas acho que dá pra melhorar, só não consegui fazer isso e também adaptar o codigo ou delphi
SELECT count(COD_CEDENTE) as total
from tbduplicatas
where COD_CEDENTE = 318
  UNION
SELECT count(COD_CEDENTE) as total
from tbvencidas
where COD_CEDENTE = 318


Da maneira como você fez, o retorno será uma única coluna com duas linhas. Acredito que seria melhor uma linha com duas colunas:
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM TBDUPLICATAS 
        WHERE COD_CEDENTE = :CEDENTE
       ) AS DUPLICATAS,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM TBVENCIDAS
        WHERE COD_CEDENTE = :CEDENTE
       ) AS VENCIDAS
 FROM RDB$DATABASE

